# pointDistance() error appears when using full my dataset in R

Tags: r, compiler-errors, distance, r-raster

Good morning,

I created functions to, from raw data, get the total distance between points with the same attributes.

It works perfectly fine with a region of the dataset, or even half of the dataset. I tried one half, and then the other half separately and both work fine. **BUT** when I try to use the full dataset an error message appears for some reason. I provide further details:

- I use pointDistance() to calculate distances (in for-loops, I have read it is faster and better)
- Points are in meters, no WGS84 coordinates (lat, lon)
- Dataset contains around 123000 observations of 4 variables

The error appears specifically when using **pointDistance(df$x, df$y, lonlat=FALSE, allpairs=FALSE)** and this is what they say (adding the Traceback):

```
 Error in .pointsToMatrix(p1) : 
  Highly suspect column names (longitude and latitude reversed?) 

6. stop("Highly suspect column names (longitude and latitude reversed?)") 
5. .pointsToMatrix(p1) 
4. pointDistance(z1[i, ], z1[i + 1, ], lonlat = FALSE, allpairs = FALSE) at Functions.r#225
3. calculate_distance(aux) at Functions.r#247
2. calculate_tracklength(aux) at Functions.r#301
1. track_length(strecke_ch, 1, 10)
```

Any suggestions? Maybe use another method or change something.

Answer (score 0):

One explanation is that is that `df` is different from the subsets that you have made. We cannot know because you provide no evidence. You should at least show some of your data, e.g. `str(df)`.

```
 pointDistance(df$x, df$y, lonlat=FALSE, allpairs=FALSE)
```

The error message suggests that you the variable names in x and y are "lat", "lon" (or some variation thereof) in that (wrong) order. But we cannot help you if you do not provide more info.

It would also be good to make a subset of `df` (e.g. 5 points) and show the values and that you can run pointDistance with these data. That is, while you may not be able to share all your data, you can make a small example, and show that the larger data set is in fact equivalent.

The `pointDistance` error occurs when you call `track_length(strecke_ch, 1, 10)`. Presumably that is your own function. The most likely cause of the problem is a mistake *before* you call `pointDistance`. But how are we to know?